# Does \lineskiplimit behave differently in header?

Tags: header-footer

In the example below, I have in the header a word with a descender and a rule. I've set `\lineskip` to be very large in order to make it obvious when `\lineskiplimit` has been reached.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[margin = 1.0in, headheight = 34.0pt]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\headrule}{}

\fancyhead[C]
{%
    \fontsize{12.0pt}{4.0pt}%
    \selectfont%
    \setlength{\lineskip}{20pt}%
    fjord%
    \\
    \rule{\textwidth}{1.0pt}%
}

\begin{document}

    \newlength{\sep} % Vertical distance between fjord and rule in header.

    \setlength{\sep}{4.0pt - 1.0pt - \depthof{fjord}}

    (baselineskip in header) - (rule height) - (depth of fjord) = \the\sep

\end{document}
```

Visually, I think we can see that `\lineskiplimit` has been reached. But, according to my calculations (see output) it certainly has not. I may have performed the wrong calculation or perhaps I do not fully understand `\lineskiplimit`. Why is there an inconsistency and what is actually happening?

[image: output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your computation would be right, weren't for the fact that `fancyhdr` adds a strut at the end of the code in the header.

I changed the code into

```
\fancyhead[C]
{%
    \fontsize{12.0pt}{4.0pt}%
    \selectfont%
    \setlength{\lineskip}{20pt}%
    fjord%
    \\
    \rule{\textwidth}{1.0pt}%
\showthe\ht\strutbox
}
```

and the message on the console showed

```
> 2.79999pt.
\f@ncyoch ...idth }{1.0pt}\showthe \ht \strutbox 
                                                 \strut
```

where the `\strut` still to be processed is visible. So the height is not `1pt`, but `2.79999pt` and `\lineskip` enters into action.

Comment: How did you know that `fancyhdr` does that? Could I have determined that from the documentation?

Comment: @fiziks I just added `\showthe\lineskiplimit` in order to see whether it was reset and spotted the `\strut`; but I had a suspect anyway. Just been lucky to catch it at the first attempt. `;-)`